# A/C now blowing hot air

Tags: vw, ac, jetta

2004 VW Jetta A/C started blowing hot air this morning on way to work. What could cause this?

Comment: Did it start off blowing cold then went warm? Or did it just start out that way this morning? Can you hear the AC compressor kick on/off?

Comment: To check the compressor start the car, switch on the Air con, open the bonnet, there will be a fan at the front near the grill, check if that fan is rotating, you should feel a sudden increase in sound of the car when the air con is ON